# Using MongoDB Collections vs Indexing

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and am trying to get my ahead around the data modelling paradigm used.

I think it's best if I provide a little background. Say I'm a company that sells stuff to customers; but the prices of my goods arn't fixed: there's a iterative bartering sequence that happens for each and every purchase. (i.e. my company quotes prices, they counter-offer, my company counter-counter offers, ect). The purpose of my database is to store the evolution of deals. My company has the ability to counter-offer with different options. The number of unique customers is <1000. As such, I have the following setup:

```
{
   customer_id : Number
   unique_deal_id: Number
   parent_unique_deal_id: Number
   child_unique_deal_id's: [Number]
   deal : {
     // info on price of each good negotiated
   }
}
```

If %100 of my queries involve a) retrieving a specific deal or b) retrieving a "branch" of deals, in MongoDB is this where I try to normalize and separate customers into their own Collections, or is the idea to keep everything in a single Collection (and index customers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the document structure is really the issue here.  Lets look at this from a different point of view.  Think of this like an accounting ledger.

```
line #, Date,  Description,   Count,  Price each
1, 02/25/2013,  Super widgets, 1000, $1   // <-- Strike though font
2, 02/25/2013, Super Widgets, 5000, $0.50 // <-- Strike though font
3, 02/26/2013, Super widgets 3500, $0.75
```

The final line #3, is the current tally.  by looking though the dates, you can see what was kept and what was not.  The "Transaction" evolves much like your account statement, just add line record item changes to the deal, and "strike" out the ones not kept (don't delete them, just mark them inactive).

I think you have 3 collections:

- Reseller - company
- Transactions (between reseller and you)
- Transactions-archive (old stuff)

  {
      _id: mongoid,
      company_id: integer,
      ... other fields...
      transaction_log: [
          { active: boolean, id: integer, date: datetime, description: text, count: integer, price: float?/integer? },
          { active: boolean, id: integer, date: datetime, description: text, count: integer, price: float?/integer? },
          { active: boolean, id: integer, date: datetime, description: text, count: integer, price: float?/integer? },
          { active: boolean, id: integer, date: datetime, description: text, count: integer, price: float?/integer? },
          ...
      ]
  }

Comment: Sorry for taking awhile to get back to you - had to grab dinner. Interesting idea though. I'm just trying to think how this translates into Mongo. By adding transactions, does this correspond to adding documents to an array, where each array keeps track of an 'opertunity'

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a design discussion that is probably best done live, but hopefully, I can steer you in the right direction.

It sounds like there are 3 main entities involved in this scenario: Customers, Deals, and Deal Bidding History. The decision to embed vs. storing data in separate collections is a design decision specific to the developer's app. I highly recommend to take the free online training course if you haven't to learn some of the basics. There is a lesson on basic schema design that will help guide you in the thought process. It looks like you already intuitively know how to make the decision as you are considering your main data access patterns.

Based on my understanding of your data, I would probably store your customer data in it's own collection. The reason being is that your app will probably access customer details independent of deals, and it doesn't appear there is a need to access customers and deals in an atomic way (Mongodb is designed to provide atomic operations at the document level). These are some reasons why duplicating customer data across all your data probably isn't the better choice. Once a customer logins, you pull customer data, and you have the context (ie. customer id). You can then use this context to read and update the deal information. Your deals collection actually looks good. With customer id, you can then pull out a deal, as well as various branches of deals (there's some references to tree design patterns on www.mongodb.org if you want to reference them--note that your design pattern does match the standard quite closely). There is one danger of embedding deal history into a deal though. Note that there is currently a 16MB limit on a single document. If you keep the deal history subdocuments lean, you should be able to store alot of history; however, if your app is like a micro bidding app then the 16MB limit may pose a problem; if this is the case, then you will need to store deal history records into individual documents in another collection. If it make sense, you may choose to store some redundant data in your deals such as the last 10 bids if it makes reads easier on your app (vs. the possibility of having to update multiple targets). In any case, embed if it is reasonable as it will provide your app simplicity and faster data access.

Also, if you end up embedding deal history into your deals, your documents will grow in size with every document. MongoDB stores documents contiguously on disk for fast updates in place and reads. The implication is that if documents grow beyond it's current allocated space, MongoDB will move the entire document to another location on disk. This can slow updates down, and maybe of concern if your application is heavy on updates. To prevent untimely document moves, look up on using the padding factor option and "powersof2" setting on the mongodb.org website.

Comment: Very informative. I did not know of the 16MB limit on document size - that may potentially be a problem for me. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Also, thanks for the "powersof2" setting reference - looks like it'll be usefull